# Interfacial surface momentum, mass and energy balances

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, energy

i have been given the following equations for an interfacial surface:

[image]

I cannot understand the physical meaning of each term. Could someone break down the significance of each term? Which terms would go to zero if we have no flux across the boundary?

Take for example the mass balance we have the normal vector for bulk phase 1 dot multiplied with the density into the relative velocity of bulk 1 with respect to the boundary minus the density of phase 2 into the relative velocity. Why are we subtracting these 2 fluxes? why is the normal vector acting as a gradient?

For the momentum balance we have the normal into the pressure plus a kinetic energy term per unit volume plus interfacial tension into the radius of curvature plus the normal dot multiplied by the viscous stress tensor of bulk 1 minus bulk 2 (is this the net traction on the interface?) is equal to the negative gradient of the interfacial tension taken at the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single phase fluid dynamics, the equations governing mass, momentum, and energy are derived using conservation laws. If you go back and look at the derivations, you'll see that the the rate of change in mass, momentum, and energy over an arbitrary volume are given by the flux into and out of this volume. The equations above are the same conservation laws just applied to a control volume that encloses an arbitrary portion of the interface.

In the interfacial mass balance, the mass into/out of fluid I must equal the mass into/out fluid II, that is $\dot{m}^I = \dot{m}^{II}$. The mass fluxes are given by
\begin{equation}
\dot{m}^I = \mathbf{n}^I \cdot\rho^I (\mathbf{v}^I - \mathbf{v}^S),\\
\dot{m}^{II} = \mathbf{n}^{I} \cdot \rho^{II} (\mathbf{v}^{II} - \mathbf{v}^S).\\
\end{equation}
If there is zero flux across the boundary, then we see that $\mathbf{v}^I = \mathbf{v}^{II} = \mathbf{v}^S$.

> Why are we subtracting these 2 fluxes? why is the normal vector acting as a gradient?

The two fluxes are subtracted only because they have manipulated the equation $\dot{m}^I = \dot{m}^{II}$. The normal vector is not acting as a gradient, it only defines which direction represents positive mass flux. In this case mass flow out of fluid I is defined as positive.

The momentum equation is the balance of forces exerted by fluid I and fluid II at the interface, that is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}^I = \mathbf{F}^{II} 
\end{equation}
At the interface the forces can be decomposed into pressure forces ($p$), surface tension forces ($\sigma$), and viscous forces ($\mathbf{\tau}$). For a more in depth explanation of the momentum balance, see this [pdf](https://web2.clarkson.edu/projects/subramanian/ch560/notes/Boundary%20Conditions%20in%20Fluid%20Mechanics.pdf).

I would also recommend reading Advanced Transport Phenomena by Gary Leal where you can find a good derivation and explanation of all of these equations.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful